# Selfstudy Conformal Field Theory and Lie algebra from scratch roadmap

Tags: resource-recommendations, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, education, lie-algebra

A couple of months ago, I stumbled upon Conformal Quantum Mechanics (CQM) which was really interesting yet confusing. I didn't have the prerequisites so I couldn't follow the paper. I want to first understand CQM then Conformal Field Theory (CFT).

I know for CFT I have to be familiar with fields and their quantizations. But my problem is mostly with Conformal groups and transformation. I don't know what are they, how to use them, and how they are applied in quantum mechanics.

I have a background in physics so I am familiar with the quantum mechanics (QM) part but not deep enough to know how to use Lie algebra in QM.

So my question what are the references and the pathway from calculus to Conformal groups and Lie algebras?

I'm willing to do whatever it's needed so just please if someone could help me, it would be a huge help.

Also I've looked at some books on group theory for physicists but I haven't seen Conformal Groups?! So, I don't know even a book on them.

Comment: Have you tried the physics section of the MIT open courses? https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-821-string-theory-fall-2008/readings/  ? I looked for "conformal"

Comment: @annav Thanks. I checked that out but it's far too advanced for me. My question is how to build up my understanding and knowledge to that level from scratch? What should I study and in what order to get there? I'd really appreciate it if you could help me and show me a direction.

Comment: I do no know your level. If I wanted to understand conformal field theory, having  sat through a field theory course,  I would go a string theory course and then the conformal part. there are a lot of courses, from undergraduate, to graduate https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/. The normal way is to do the classical mechanics and classical electromagnetic, thermodynamics; , then first level quantum mechanis. higher level, field theory , string theory with an elementary particle course to understand what thewhole fuss is about: finding a theory that describes and predicts observations and data.